# Best practices to organize pods in kubernates

Tags: kubernetes

I have a project that uses the following resources to work:

- A jsf application running under JBoss and using a PostgreSQL
- 2 spring boot API using MongoDB.

So, I have the following dockers:

- jsf+JBoss in same docker
- PostgreSQL docker
- mongo docker
- one docker for each spring boot app.

In kubernates I need organize this containers in PODs, so my ideia is create the following:

- A POD for jsf+JBoss docker
- Another for PostgreSQL
- Another POD for MongoDB
- Only one POD for both spring boot app, because they need each other.

So, I have 4 POD and 6 containers. Thinking about best practices to use ks8, this is a good way to organize my project?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but I don't see any issue with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr; This doesn't follow Kubernetes best practices. Each application should be a separate [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) or [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

A better way to run this in Kubernetes would be using a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) or [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for each individual application, so it would be:

One Deployment with a single container for jsf+JBoss

One StatefulSet for PostgreSQL (though I would suggest looking at an Operator to manage your PostgreSQL cluster, i.e. [kubedb](https://kubedb.com/)

One StatefulSet for MongoDB (again, strongly suggest using an Operator to manage your MongoDB cluster, which [kubedb](https://kubedb.com/) can also handle)

One deployment *each* for your Spring Boot applications, assuming they communicate with each other via a network. You can then manage and scale each independently of each other, regardless of their dependency on each other.

Comment: Thanks for help, very useful.